# Trying to insulate a radiator steam pipe exposed in my bedroom

Tags: insulation, radiant-barrier

Have an exposed radiator pipe in my bedroom, which clearly supplies steam to other units in the building, so its always "on", regardless of whether my radiator is on or not. This makes the room unbearably hot.

I've looked into some products online, but I'm a little wary of how to proceed.

Fiberglass wrap insulation. Seems effective, but dangerous? A lot of stories of getting rashes from installing it, of the potential for fiberglass to escape into the air, etc. Example = [https://www.amazon.com/Frost-King-Foil-Backed-Fiberglass/dp/B000BQSMCG/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BQSMCG)

Foam wrap insulation. Seems less effective, but safer? Example = [https://www.amazon.com/Pipe-Insulation-Foam-Tube-Foil/dp/B09FDHV8GS/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09FDHV8GS)

Foam tube insulation. Basically, these seem like pool noodles? If they are fire retardant, does that mean that they are non-toxic to have in a bedroom, pressed against a very hot pole at all times? Example = [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CJC6PVNC/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CJC6PVNC)

Radiator Pole dimensions are:

Diameter = 1.75in

Height = ~118in (the pipe runs vertically from floor to ceiling)

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: https://thermtest.com/thermal-resources/top-10-resources/top-10-thermally-resistive-materials-and-gases

Answer (score 1):

A fairly common way to deal with this is to wrap a fairly thick manila or sisal rope around the pipe. I've seen this in many apartments. It is cheap and easy, non-toxic, and works well unless you have a cat.

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Steam pipe with rope around it]

Here's the blog describing it:

https://renov8or.blogspot.com/2019/10/rope-wrap-exposed-steam-pipe.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's a steam pipe, not a hot water pipe, you'll have to stick with an insulation that will take 250°F/121°C and that will likely be fiberglass. I mean, you could use silica-free ceramic fiber isulation, but it has a price that reflects it being rated for 10X the temperature you need. Many of the foam insulations will melt.

Wear long sleeves and gloves, which is how you avoid a rash, seal the outer jacket well, so it's not able to shed any fibers, and vacuum when done.

But first, see if you can have building maintenance take care of it, rather that you having to do it, as it's a building system, not your own private hot thing that should be your job to insulate properly.

Rockwool/stone wool/mineral wool is another option, but not as common in consumer outlets for pipe insulation. It is made for that purpose, however.

### However

It appears that EDPM foam rubber (specifically that) does have an upper operating range [of 257°F](https://aeroflexusa.com/what-is-epdm-insulation/) and even a higher-temperature formulation (you don't need) rated [to 150°C](https://cbfrost-rubber.com/materials/sponge-rubber/high-temperature-epdm-sponge/) Usually the EDPM is the most expensive of the various types of foam pipe insulation on offer at a typical hardware supplier (or they may not carry it.) Any HVAC specialist supply should have a lot of it in stock, though.

Whatever you use, a shiny foil outer layer will reduce radiation to the room.